# Tabstop-like alignment of text possible?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabbing

I'd like to format some text around a tabstop such that 
what is left from the tabstop is `\flushright` and
the text that is right from the line is `\flushright`. The Tabstop is at a specific position, for example 2.5cm away from the left margin.

Example:
**Some Text on the left side** | some text, on the right side 
         |  that continues over some paragraphs
**some other text** | some further text

**more text** |  further text

and all `|` are at 2.5cm from left margin, so that it looks a little bit like this:

[image]

I tried to use the tabular environment, but that does not allow me to specify the 2.5cm correctly.

A solution without further packages is prefered.

Answer (score 9):

You could try something like the following (a `tabular` environment with two `p{...}` columns):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.3cm}@{\hspace{0.2cm}}p{6cm}@{}}
\hfill\bfseries work& text \\
\hfill\bfseries home & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\par text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3cm}\=  \kill
\bfseries work \' \url{steve@apple.com} \\
\bfseries home \'  text text text text text 
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For others landing here with similar `tabbing` questions, consider also `` \` `` for (different) right-alignment. See [tabbing documentation](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/tabbing.html) for further description and differences between `foo\'` (at right in previous column) and `` \`foo `` (at right in current/last column).

Comment: That does not work for me, I have to use `\>` and also add a `\\\` to the end of the second row.

Comment: Ask a new question and show your code and output.